# Access a Xamarin Component's buttons (specifically the iOS card.io component)

Tags: ios, xamarin, card.io

The card.io component (http://components.xamarin.com/view/cardioios) has a fallback screen that has a Cancel and a Done button on them.

Neither of which actually do anything.  I assume it is up to me to subscribe to and event, however, there is no event to subscribe to.

Here is the code:

```
var paymentDelegate = new PaymentViewControllerDelegate();
var paymentViewController = new Card.IO.PaymentViewController(paymentDelegate);
paymentDelegate.OnScanCompleted += (viewController, cardInfo) =>
{
    viewController.DismissViewController(true, null);

    if (cardInfo == null)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        new UIAlertView("Card Scanned!", cardInfo.CardNumber, null, "OK", null).Show();
    }
};

paymentViewController.AppToken = "app-token";

// Display the card.io interface
base.PresentViewController(paymentViewController, true, () => { });
```

There is a method on the PaymentViewControllerDelegate, but I can't figure out what to do with it:

```
 public override void UserDidCancel(PaymentViewController paymentViewController);
 public override void UserDidProvideCreditCardInfo(CreditCardInfo cardInfo, PaymentViewController paymentViewController);
```

I guess the problem is that the Component doesn't expose any events for the Fallback View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured this out by looking at the working sample application and comparing it to what I had done.

All I had to do was widen the scope of the paymentDelegate and paymentViewController variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass `PaymentViewControllerDelegate`:

```
public class MyPaymentDelegate : PaymentViewControllerDelegate
{
    public MyPaymentDelegate ()
    {
    }
    public override void UserDidCancel (PaymentViewController paymentViewController)
    {
        // Implement on-cancel logic here...
        base.UserDidCancel (paymentViewController);
    }

    public override void UserDidProvideCreditCardInfo (CreditCardInfo cardInfo, PaymentViewController paymentViewController)
    {
        // Implement logic for credit card info provided here...
        base.UserDidProvideCreditCardInfo (cardInfo, paymentViewController);
    }
}
```

And then provide an instance of this class into the constructor for `Card.IO.PaymentViewController`:

```
var paymentDelegate = new MyPaymentDelegate();
var paymentViewController = new Card.IO.PaymentViewController(paymentDelegate);
```

Comment: I tried that, doesn't seem to have worked.  I can't hit the breakpoints while debugging and can't dismiss the paymentViewController..         public override void UserDidCancel(Card.IO.PaymentViewController paymentViewController)
        {
            paymentViewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
            base.UserDidCancel(paymentViewController);
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the sample, you really just need to subscribe to the `OnScanCompleted` event which is called in both cases of `UserDidCancel` (where cardInfo will be null), and `UserDidProvideCreditCardInfo` (where it will not be null).

In fact, this is the code for the binding, so you can see the Event was made as a 'helper' to make it so you didn't have to make your own delegate implementation:

```
namespace Card.IO
{
    public partial class PaymentViewControllerDelegate : BasePaymentViewControllerDelegate
    {
        public delegate void ScanCompleted(PaymentViewController viewController, CreditCardInfo cardInfo);
        public event ScanCompleted OnScanCompleted;

        public override void UserDidCancel (PaymentViewController paymentViewController)
        {
            var evt = OnScanCompleted;
            if (evt != null)
                evt(paymentViewController, null);
        }

        public override void UserDidProvideCreditCardInfo (CreditCardInfo cardInfo, PaymentViewController paymentViewController)
        {
            var evt = OnScanCompleted;
            if (evt != null)
                evt(paymentViewController, cardInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

If you still really want to implement the delegate yourself, subclass `BasePaymentViewController` instead, however I don't think you really need to make your own subclass of it...

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Also you are talking about the fallback view specifically having a cancel button... When running on device here I don't see a cancel button on the fallback view, you can just click the button to go back.
Are you just using an old device that it starts in this fallback view?  I'm having a hard time understanding where the problem is...